# Displaying a ssrs report on a Tab in a MS Teams Channel

Tags: reporting-services, microsoft-teams

Not sure if this is in scope but I will ask.

Can you display an internal SSRS report on a Tab in a Microsoft Teams Channel tab?

I have a report server (which has only been live a few months) report of format

```
http://<MyServer>/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2f<FolderPath>%2f<MyReportName>&rs:Command=Render
```

I have tried using the Reportserver address with the paths in a MS Teams website addon but am aware of the https:// requirement

it appears https://ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2f%2f&rs:Command=Render

Only gives an message of
[image]

Which makes sense as the Reportserver address is not https

So

1. Can you connect a SSRS report in a teams channel, is there a recommend method?
2. Can anyone advise how to get round the secure connection problem? Please bear in mind this is a live SSRS server so if I make changes what will I "break" or "risk breaking"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been ages since I worked with SSRS, but if you're using it hosted in IIS natively, then it might be possible to add an additional endpoint (i.e. to have SSRS answer ALSO on, for example, [httpS://SSRS.YourCompany.com/[rest](httpS://SSRS.YourCompany.com/%5Brest) of url]. Something like [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/83726f35-fd08-40ab-85b1-16301c98b2ba/need-to-set-up-ssrs-with-host-header-and-ssl?forum=sqlreportingservices) should help. This assumes you have an appropriate SSL/TLS certificate (e.g. matching "SSRS.YourCompany.com", or a "wilcard" cert matching *.YourCompany.com, that you can use.

Importantly, this new address should render fine in the browser, WITHOUT any SSL/TLS security issues appearing in the browser.

Once that's working, it should be easy enough to add it as a tab in Teams.